# Understanding Table Coordinate system in Python ReportLab

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I am having trouble understanding the coordinate system for `ReportLab` table styles.

According to their documentation:

*The first element of each command is its identifier, the second and third arguments determine the cell
coordinates of the box of cells which are affected with negative coordinates counting backwards from the
limit values as in Python indexing.*

*The coordinates are given as (column, row) which follows the
spreadsheet 'A1' model, but not the more natural (for mathematicians) 'RC' ordering. The top left cell is (0, 0)
the bottom right is (-1, -1)*

If the bottom right is always (-1, -1), does that mean the mid rows and columns are fractional? That doesn't seem to makes sense. Given the below example, how is the green starting at position (1,1) is the coordinate system goes from 0 to -1 and how does the second coordinate system (-2,-2) offset from the origin position?

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table.pdf", pagesize=letter)
# container for the 'Flowable' objects
elements = []

data= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
       ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
       ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
       ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]
t=Table(data)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.green),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(1,-1),colors.red)]))
elements.append(t)
# write the document to disk
doc.build(elements)
```

[image]

Comment: those tables styles are applied to cells not pixel coordinates

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I know, but my question still applies to them being table coordinates. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I guess I dont understand your question ... you dont ned to use negative ordering ... `TABLE[-1,-1]` in this case is exactly the same as `TABLE[3,4]` in python you can access the end of the list with -1 so TABLE[-1] is the last row TABLE[-1][-1] is simply the last column of the last row (maybe i got my row/column order switched)

Comment: So the negative one is not like subtracting one from the origin position?

Comment: Same question here. How does the TABLE stop being rendered in green at [-2][-2] as specified in the code?

Comment: @alextc. I figured it out and posted an answer to my own question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally figured it out so posting my own answer. You have to think of negative and positive coordinate systems being completely independent of each other. The positive system starts at [1][1] in the top left corner and increments numbers as you go down and to the right. The negative system starts at [-1][-1] as decreases (larger negatives) as you go up and to the left.

In this example, `('BACKGROUND',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.green)` The two coordinates, while using different relative starting position define a the upper left and lower right corners of a box.

Comment: I am still confused. How can coordinates with (1,1) and (-2, -2) be a perfect rectangle at the center of the table? I am not sure what you are referring to in the [1][1] and [-1][-1] positive and negative systems. Why are they in brackets? I gotta say reportlab's style is quite weird even interchanging the rows and columns from the normal

Comment: Okay I get it now. Absolutely weird way of structuring by reportlab. But basically the first cell in the upper left is (0, 0) and the most lower right cell is (-1, -1) so a coordinate of (1, 1) in the 2nd argument of `TableStyle` is (one cell right, one cell down) relative to (0, 0) and a coordinate of (-2, -2) in the 3rd argument of `TableStyle` is (one cell left, one cell up) relative to  (-1, -1). This is my understanding to it. I believe the answer above is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Reportlab coordinates for a table (sample)]

Now imagine your table is of size (5,4), then this would be the kind of coordinates that you will need to follow!

Answer (score 4):

I have found it is easier to think of the cells as lists rather that coordinates for this issue.  Top left cell is (0,0) and the last column in this example is 4 which can also be represented as -1, just like a list.  The second to last column in this example is 3 which can also be -2, etc.

I found challenging the fact that the cell references are (col, row) rather than (row, col).

Comment: Plus one for quick preview. Table coordinate system uses mix of reversed cartesian system and list indexing. List indexing allows define cells from the end. Therefore can be used when you don't know, how many cells the table will have.